# Drupal 7 Navigation link target = "_blank"

Tags: drupal-7

Is there a way to add an external navigation link with target = "_blank" in drupal 7? I can get the link added but not with target = "_blank"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://drupal.org/project/menu_attributes

good luck